# Are CPU coolers for LGA 775 compatible with LGA 1155 CPUs?

Tags: cpu, lga775

I have a fancy CPU cooler for my older LGA 775 Intel CPU. I want to upgrade to an LGA 1155, including a new motherboard and RAM. Would I be able to re-use the CPU cooler? Or would I need a new one (using either the OEM cooler or buying another aftermarket cooler)?

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so I've purchased a LGA 1155 motherboard (ASRock P67 Extreme4) which has 775 cooler mounting holes, I'll update this again after attempting an install.

**UPDATE 2:**

It works! The cpu cooler mounts at a slight angle though which is a little annoying, but other than that seems good. I can overclock from 3.3GHz to 4.2GHz, and the highest core temp I hit under load is 68C, so I'm pretty happy still.

Comment: Like @Shinrai mentions the heatsink has to fit the motherboard (needs mounting points) and it has to match the CPU size itself. If 775 and 1156/1155 don't have significant size differences, this question would only dependent on the mounting.

Comment: @Ivo Flipse - LGA775, LGA1156, and LGA1155 are all a 3.75cm by 3.75cm package size.

Comment: Awesome, that's actually good new for me too, I want to keep my 'fancy' watercooling

Comment: @Ivo Flipse - Basically 1155 is identical to 1156 except for being keyed differently on the processor socket itself (well, and the missing pin).

Comment: My current water block is 775, is there any way to mount this on a 1155 motherboard? I've seen plenty adapters, but I have no idea if they and how they work

Comment: @Ivo Flipse - It'll depend on the block.  The backplates may be a little different so you might have to break out the Dremel.  (I've actually heard this has been a slight issue from 1156 to 1155 but that's more of a poor motherboard design issue, the spec is identical.)

Comment: FWIW, for anybody else having this problem: while 99% of 775's won't fit 1155 nor 1150, you can just remove the mounts and refit them with custom screws - it's certainly doable, it just takes some tools and a bit of mechanical engineering. Google "mounting lga 775 fan on lga 1155" or "mounting lga 775 fan on lga 1150" to see how it can be done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mount points are different.  However, there are some motherboards hitting the market with the appropriate holes for 775 mounting in addition to 1155/1156 mounting.  Assuming you can find a motherboard with appropriate mount points, the heatsink itself will probably work fine.  (Also note that if your heatsink is fancy enough, the manufacturer MAY have an adapter kit available.)

Comment: After extensive searching on the internet you can purchase them as well...

Comment: @KronoS - 1155 mounting is identical to 1156 mounting.  Therefore there are hundreds of aftermarket coolers that'll work just fine. :)

Comment: Faced with this exact issue this morning, I stumbled across a prime example of this --ASRock Z75 Pro3.